# Classic ASP: 32-bit dll running slow in 64-bit windows 2003 R2 AFTER domain change

Tags: pdf, iis, asp-classic, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2003-r2

My Classic ASP app is using COM version of ActiveReports to get data out of a very small SQL server 2008 database (less than 200MB) and generating PDFs on request from the simple ASP app. The PDF size is about 8KB. The ASP server runs on W2k3R2 64-bit.  I had done the following:

1. Used regsvr32 in SysWOW64 to register the DLLs
2. Enabled 32-bit support for IIS running under 64-bit WinOS

The ASP server was on the UAT domain while we were testing, and it used to be able to produce the PDF reports within 5 seconds...then the management decided to 'join' the PROD domain instead; and for some strange reasons, the PDF generation processes took 1-5 minutes instead of seconds.  Regardless on unregistering/registering the DLLs again, numerous IIS restarts, adding IUSRS and IWAM users into the local admin group, and re-enabling 32-bit support within IIS, there is  no improvements in performance.

Using the SQL profiler, we are 100% sure the bottleneck is not caused by SQL connections, but the generation of PDFs.

We are totally baffling with this problem, is there anything else we should look at, apart from changing server (as a last resort)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pause can be caused by attempt to access to the printer settings in the rendering engine, please try to use MyReport.Printer.DeviceName = "" code before MyReport.Run()

Comment: Exactly the problem!  We ended up disabling server printer service and the whole system runs like a dream.  Thanks mate.